# Using mysqli query object as a set in subsequent query

Tags: php, mysqli

I am working on a reservation system for a local resort which is accessed via reasonably secure LAN only, as such I am not immediately concerned with SQL injection.  My main concern is the functionality to lookup up reservations based upon the PK(s) returned by a query on individual guests. To do this, I have been using the mysqli query object returned by a query of a table containing guest information:

```
$get_guest_id = "SELECT id FROM guests WHERE fname = '$fname' OR lname = '$lname' OR phone = '$phone' OR email = '$email'";
$guest_id_result = mysqli_query($con, $get_guest_id);
```

I have tried using this query object as I would a set within mySQL:

```
$search_by_id = "SELECT * FROM reservation WHERE guest_id IN '$guest_id_result'";
```

But this does not return as expected:

> Returns false on failure. For successful queries which produce a result set, such as SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE or EXPLAIN, mysqli_query() will return a mysqli_result object. For other successful queries, mysqli_query() will return true.

Rather than returning true, false, or a result set, the PHP script stops executing at this statement.

Is there a different way to pass the data contained within a mysqli query object to another query, in a manner similar to a set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're trying to cast an object into a string for your query...

The best solution would probably be to turn the two queries into a singular one, additionally updating the code to use a prepared statement.

### Query

```
SELECT * FROM reservations
WHERE guest_id IN (SELECT id
    FROM guests
    WHERE fname  = ?
        OR lname = ?
        OR phone = ?
        OR email = ?
);
```

### Code

```
$sql = "
    SELECT * FROM reservations
    WHERE guest_id IN (SELECT id
        FROM guests
        WHERE fname  = ?
            OR lname = ?
            OR phone = ?
            OR email = ?
    );
";

$query  = $con->prepare($sql);
$query->bind_param("ssss", $fname, $lname, $phone, $email);
$query->execute();
$result = $query->get_result();

while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo $row["guest_id"], PHP_EOL; // Example output printing the guest_id of guests with reservations (followed by a newline)
}
```